# Blank page when using children routes with no errors

Tags: angular, routes

I am trying to change some code in my project and I have started with routes

I have a menu with options that have [routerLink];

This is how my routing module looked like:

```
const routes: Routes = [
      { path: 'account-settings/account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
      { path: 'account-settings/password', component: PasswordComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
      { path: 'account-settings/certificate', component: CertificateComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
      { path: 'account-settings/notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
      { path: 'account-settings/preferences', component: PreferencesComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
      { path: 'account-settings/security', component: SecurityComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' } },
]
```

as you can see, every route has account-settings so I created a new component AccountSettings

```
<div class="container padding-80">
    <h4 class="accountSettings-title">Account settings</h4>
</div>
<div class="container main justify-content-center">
    <div class="row account-content">
        <div class="col-3 account-sidebar">
            <account-settings-sidebar></account-settings-sidebar>
        </div>
        <div class="menu col-9">
            test
            <router-outlet></router-outlet>>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

AccountSettingsSidebar has buttons like this

```
 <button [routerLink]="['/learning/account-settings/account']" [routerLinkActive]="['active']" type="button" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      <p><i-feather name="user" data-feather="user" class="sidebar-icons"></i-feather>Account</p>
 </button>
```

I have changed the routing module using a main route for account settings and children for every route I have showed you above, using this link https://angular-2-training-book.rangle.io/routing/child_routes.

My problem is that when I try to access any route (for example, account-settings/account) I get a blank page, no errors and no components in DOM.
Where am I wrong here?

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'account-settings', component: AccountSettingsComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full', canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'account', component: AccountComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'password', component: PasswordComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'preferences', component: PreferencesComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }},
      { path: 'security', component: SecurityComponent, canActivate: [LearningRedirectGuard], data: { menuType: 'learning' }}
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: always add this route { path: '**', redirectTo: 'account' } to handle when user enters another route other than specified ones. remember to add it always as last one.

Comment: Try this ` { path: '**', redirectTo: 'account', pathMatch: 'full'}`. You don't need to add canActivate on redirection.